# PHP SQL Search With Duplicate Entries

Tags: php, sql, arrays, duplicates

I'm trying to make a search that will look for either a last name or a first name in a database then have it return those values and echo them out. I have gotten that far but where I'm getting stuck is when there is a duplicate entry such as a first name.

Ex; 2 entries within the database have the same FirstName Value as Bill and different LastName Values

How can i return all the ones with the same first name value? I've tried multiple solutions but have not been able to get it. I feel like I'm missing something really easy but I'm being blind and can't see it.

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM RWApplicants GROUP BY FirstName HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1");
                        $r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        if($r){

                                echo "first";
                                print_r($r);}
```

Gives me only the first row but not the others

I've tried that and different variations of it..Hopefully anyone can help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing DB libraries. using `->query()` suggests you're using PDO or mysqli. But then you try to get the actual result rows with `mysql_fetch_array()`.

The "big three" libraries (mysql, mysqli, and PDO) are **NOT** interchangeable, and connection/result handles from one library are utterly useless in the others.

Since you're using pdo/mysqli, the mysql_fetch call will return a boolean FALSE to indicate failure, not an array of data.

Comment: That would make sense, I'm mainly trying to stick to PDO, instead of mysql_fetch_array() what should i be using?

Comment: You've already got `->fetch()`  above. `$r` will be a row of data from the result set.

Comment: while using ->fetch() how can i display all the information within $r?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php  it'll return the data however you want. by default it's a dual-keyed array.

Comment: I've changed the code to 
                            '$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM RWApplicants WHERE FirstName ='$Search'");
                            $r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            if($r){
                                echo "first";
                                print_r($r);'

but it only displays the first row instead of both of them

Comment: better is to run the query, then check how many rows were returned. or just `while($r = ....) { print_r($r); }` to fetch anything in a loop.

Comment: for the `while($r = ....){ print_r($r);}` what am i comparing $r to in the while statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues, but I'll see if I can't help you.  It could be that mixed methods of DB access are the issue, but there's also an irregularity in the code itself...

> while($f=mysql_fetch_array()){ 
>      $FirstName  =$result['FirstName'];

You assign "$f" as the iterator, and then echo $result?

Here's a more standard approach that should work:

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM RWApplicants WHERE FirstName ='$Search'");
$r = $query->fetch();
if($r){
   while($f=mysql_fetch_array($r)){ 
       $FirstName  =$f['FirstName']; 
       $LastName=$f['LastName']; 
       $ID=$f['ID']; 
      echo "<ul>\n<li>" .$FirstName . " " . $LastName .  "</li>\n</ul>"; 
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to change that back to $r but i was trying to do some troubleshooting lol!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find duplicate FirstName entries try using this

```
("SELECT * FROM RWApplicants GROUP BY FirstName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1")
```

Try this if you want to get all the rows with  duplicate FirstName

```
("SELECT * FROM RWApplicants WHERE FirstName IN(SELECT FirstName FROM RWApplicants GROUP BY FirstName HAVING count(*) > 1)");
```